# Prevent numerical values in kendo textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-validator

I am creating a sample book library application using asp.net MVC in which i am using kendo UI tools, i want use Book title or author fields in which i want to prevent a user from entering numerical values, allowing only A-Z, how will i use kendoValidator to do that.
below is my input

```
<input id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle" type="text" class="k-textbox" value="#= Title #" />
```

This is where i want to do the validation

```
return $("#bookDiv").kendoValidator({
        rules: {
            Title: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[name=txtTitle]") && input.val() == ""))
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a `regex` and `match`:

```
(input.is("[name=txtTitle]") && input.val() == "" && input.val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)))
```

`/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` means

- search from the beginning of the string until the end. (`^` till `$`)
- Search for a-z and A-Z
- `+` for all characters until the end of the string.

For a match the string needs to be a-z entirely. If there is a match it will not return `null` and pass.

> On a side note: This will not allow any other character. Diacritics like é will not pass.

Comment: Still not working for me, do i have to add some kendovalidator specific attribute to my input or not needed

Comment: Still you need to call the validator on submit/blur of the input/form, setting it on a `div` will not let it auto validate. Setting it on a form auto validates when the user submits.

Comment: yep i am already doing that " var validator = applyValidator();
    and then if (validator.validate()) { my code here after validation}); "

Comment: Please update your post with the full code for validation'. Your problem isn't reproduceable  at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a custom rule, you could use Kendo UI's built in pattern validator.

```
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" value="#=Title#" pattern="[^0-9]+" />
```

[Kendo UI API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/validator/overview#default-validation-rules)